# Vue 3 duplicate identifier ref

Tags: javascript, typescript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, vuejs3

I'm having some trouble trying to make a simple Vue3 + Firebase application.

The problem is that when importing the needed modules, two of them are called the same way: `ref`.

```
import { computed, defineComponent, ref } from "vue";
import { getDatabase, ref, child, get } from "firebase/database";
```

I need those two ref(s) imports, one for a chart, and the other one for the firebase connection, but, code does not work because i get the error `Duplicate identifier "ref"`

And in console I see:

[image]

Where, in line 85 of App.vue I have the use of the ref by firebase (but using the module from Vue, not from firebase/database"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you try to use [`import`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import) alias:

```
import { getDatabase, ref as fbRef, child, get } from "firebase/database";
```